# a standard way to implement a device configuration

Tags: design-patterns, configuration

I have the following problem: I have a software that shows (video)input from multiple devices. The devices have different interface and different configurable properties (like resolution, fps, output format etc). I want to implement it in a way that each device kind of exposes its properties, I create a dynamically changing GUI (that is created based on the possible properties) and use this GUI to configure the device run-time. The question is, is there any standard design pattern to implement it? Now I have a class for each device, that has some common interface to retrieve video data, but the configuration interface is device-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any design patterns for this situation but i deal with it using either reflection at run-time to find out the available properties and their types and then create a UI control suitable for that, or if you like you can use an interface that looks something like this:

```
public interface IConfigurableDevice {
    IDictionary<String, Object> DeviceProperties { get; }
}
```

Then you can have all your devices implementing this interface so they return all their properties as (name, value) pairs in the dictionary, in other words i try to let the interface of my device configuration expose meta-data about the properties the device has and then leverage that meta-data to build the UI.